# stm32f103 memory addressing

Tags: embedded, stm32

I have written my code for stm32f103c8t6 board in keil using tha adequate startup files. I wrote directly to the memory addresses using information from the datasheet. but the st-link upload seems to upload the hex file to the worng addresses for example :
GPIOA = 0X4001 0800
This is according to the stm datasheet.
But stlink shows the device data range from 0x0800 0000 to 0x0800 03d4.
My code is a simple program to blink the led at portA1. i connected the led across a 10k resistor. Why is stm assigning the wrong addresses when i used pointers to specify the memory locations, or could there be any other mistakes. Code below.

```
void delay(int a);

int main(void)
{
unsigned int* GPIO_A;
GPIO_A = (unsigned int*)0x40010800 ; // Assigning GPIOA to the correct   memory location

unsigned int* GPIO_A_CRL;
GPIO_A_CRL = GPIO_A + 0x00 ; // Assigning GPIO_A_CRL to the correct memory location

/*unsigned int* GPIO_A_IDR;
GPIO_A_IDR = GPIO_A + 0X08 ; // Assigning GPIO_A_IDR to the correct memory location  */

unsigned int* GPIO_A_BSRR;
GPIO_A_BSRR = GPIO_A + 0X10 ; // Assigning GPIO_A_BSRR to the correct memory location

unsigned int* GPIO_A_BRR;
GPIO_A_BRR = GPIO_A + 0X14 ; // Assigning GPIO_A_BSRR to the correct memory   location

 unsigned int* RCC_APB2ENR;
 RCC_APB2ENR = (unsigned int*)(0x40021000 + 0X18) ; // Assigning        RCC_APB2ENR to the correct memory location

*RCC_APB2ENR = 0X04; // Set clock for GPIOA

*GPIO_A_CRL = 0X00008888 ; // Defining pin modes for GPIO_A_CRL

while(1)  // infinite loop
{
    *GPIO_A_BSRR = 0X00000002;  // Set bit 1 to 1
    delay(2); // delay
    *GPIO_A_BRR = 0x00000002;  // reset bit 1 to reset value(0)
    delay(2); // delay
}

}
void delay(int a)
{
long b = a*1000000;
for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
   {
    int c=1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to you that put your question in [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I have many examples for this chip that directly access the registers not using a library https://github.com/dwelch67/stm32_samples/tree/master/STM32F103C8T6 including how to load using the serial bootloader or stlink.

Comment: Have you been able to program this part with the tools you have using any other example of any kind?  I think when I first got these parts I had to unlock the flash, then once done, they were a lot easier to program.

Comment: note you need a lot of volatiles in your code for it to work properly if you ever optimize, dont think that is your problem yet.

Comment: I think your code is fine otherwise, enable port a, then the minimum for that chip is one csr and then the bsrr to change the output should only need the bsrr though.

Comment: I am new to stm, please how do I unlock the flash .

Comment: If this is one of those $1 or $2 china/asia ebay boards I think the led is on PC13 (port c not port a), but you could put your own or a scope on port a, your call..

Comment: i am using an external led , on a breadboard across a 10k resistor

Comment: And yes it is a chinese board. I am thinking , do i have to make any other extra clock settings like speed or sth , are there are parameters i am missing

Comment: If my notes are correct (I have them in an email didnt post them on github yet for some reason)  from openocd (via the stlink) I think it was as simple as stm32f1x unlock 0, re-reading my email that was for a different stm32 and not sure if I have a virgin stm32f104 to try this on.

Comment: you can certainly use the serial interface as I describe in my README (there is code you can use there) you do a read_unprotect or maybe it is the write_unprotect(), the bootloader will puke but you then power cycle and the board is not flashable from stlink or serial

Comment: how do i unlock the flash you said sth about that i still dont understand how to do it ?

Comment: Any reason yyou don't use the CMSIS headers provided by ST for the device? It defines types and macro for all peripheral registers and the CPU intrinsics, etc.

Comment: I want to learn the hard way. And i find direct access to the memory  locations easier

Comment: At least a few of us in the world need to know how things really work so that libraries, etc can continue to be made for the folks that dont.  All for anyone who wants to learn this knowledge.  At the same time as a professional you are responsible, cant blame some vendors library when your product fails (well you can try).  Libraries and headers like that are a royal PITA to wade through side by side with the chip documentation to understand what they are doing what registers and bits they are accessing, a bit of a nightmare to validate that code properly.  less is more.

Comment: as you see all over stackoverflow and others I do recommend that bare metal programmers learn multiple paths, really bare talking to registers directly like this (these mcus are pretty easy to program this is often the easiest path), and to try the various libraries.  Professionally you may be asked to take over code in any of these forms and the more experience you have the better.  Likewise you may find a favorite way of doing it, and I still recommend re-evaluating every so often to see if the thing you werent doing is now better than it was before.

Comment: @ched I may or may not depending have spoon fed you too much of this, part of working at this level is switching tools (openocd vs an ide) switching from SWD (jtagish) to the serial bootloader, figuring out from the manual how to get into the serial bootloader mode.  Finding and/or writing your own host code to talk to the serial bootloader, debugging that if your code or the one you borrowed doesnt work.  Programming the mcu registers to make it do something is the trivial part, the reading, understanding, and beating on tools is often the hard part.

Comment: I think we are drifting off topic here please, can anyone help me ?

Comment: @old_timer  I have a question, does the write protection on the processor prevent my code from running or does it only prevent debugging ?

Comment: only programming the flash.  you should still be able to download to ram and run from ram.

Comment: @old_timer but the IDE shows that the flash was successfully programmed,does it mean that my problems originate from somewhere else, or the IDE reports wrongly?

Comment: can you use a/the debugger to dump some number of words at address 0x08000000 then compare them to the disassembly/listing of your binary?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler/linker has not assigned addresses incorrectly; you have simply misunderstood the memory map and how the compiler and linker (and even the processor) work.

0x08000000 to 0x080003d4 is the location of your *code*; 0X40010800 is the address of the GPIOA memory mapped register.

On the STM32 0x0800000 is the start address of the on-chip flash memory.  When the processor comes out of reset it loads the stack-pointer register from 0x08000000 and the program-counter register from 0x08000004.  Above this is the [interrupt vector table](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABIFJFG.html) and above that will be your code - or rather the machine-code generated by compiler from your source code.  The start-up file you mentioned define amongst other things the reset and interrupt vectors mentioned.

The pointer `GPIO_A` is assigned in your code at *runtime*, the location of the *pointer variable* will be in RAM, although since you intialise it and never modify it the compiler may optimise to store the address in ROM or replace it with a literal in-line.

Rather then defining your own register addresses, it would be far simpler and safer to use the vendor supplied processor header (stm32f10xx.h in this case)  The Keil tool chain includes this file when you configure a project for a specific part.  It also includes the STM32 standard peripheral library (or download it from [here](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-libraries/stsw-stm32054.html)) which simplifies low-level peripheral access and includes numerous examples for peripheral I/O including GPIO.

For complete programmer information on STM32F1xx, it is not sufficient to rely on the datasheet - that just tells you the part specific features; there is a more comprehensive [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf) that you should use.

Comment: yeah, i have read about it and i understand now, but the code is still not working. i get error accessing target resource on the debug, illegal address 0x08000000

Comment: Also , I know about the headers, but i want to learn it the hard way, since it is a simple project

Comment: @ched :  Learning the addresses of the registers is not "the hard way", it is the pointless way.  The next processor you use will be completely different.  Moreover using the standard register names will make your code more portable and allow you to more easily use third-party code.  There are levels; low-level register definitions, the standard-peripheral library, and the STM32Cube framework.  Using the low-level register definitions is not "the easy way", it is doing just what you have done, only more comprehensively and accurately.

Comment: Regarding your errors connecting the debugger; that is a different question; post a new one.  In Keil, you need to select the matching device for your project *and* select the correct flash programming driver.  If you post a question, the version of MDK-ARM and type of debug hardware you are using should be specified.

Comment: thanks but I find it easier to write to the registers, it makes mre sense to me. But I will try the GPIO libraries. I have a question, does the write protection on the processor prevent my code from running or does it only prevent debugging ?

Comment: If you have another question, post another question.  Why would write protection prevent execution?  That would be entirely self-defeating!  I presume you mean read-out protection in any case as write protection would not prevent debugging either.

Comment: but the IDE shows that the flash was successfully programmed,does it mean that my problems originate from somewhere else, or the IDE reports wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

I think your data range is correct. Pointers reside in RAM just like any other variables. It is not where they reside that matters but what they are pointing at, in your case the GPIO. The code looks kind of correct, that said I have not checked the addresses are correct for the registers you wish to write or that you are writing the correct values / registers. Try enabling the clock first. If in doubt have a look at a GPIO example in the F3 cube download from ST. It uses their library functions but you can have look inside them. It also provides a file which contains definitions for all the registers which I suggest you use.

Comment: yeah, i have read about it and i understand now, but the code is still not working. i get error accessing target resource on the debug, illegal address 0x08000000

Answer (score 0):

I have an ebay $2 from asia that has this same part and an led on Port C pin 13.

This is a complete gnu toolchain based example, which you can change to operate on port d pin 0 (or move your led to pc13)

flash.s

```
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .
```

blinker01.c

```
#define GPIOCBASE 0x40011000
#define RCCBASE 0x40021000
#define RCC_APB2ENR   (*((volatile unsigned int *)(RCCBASE+0x18)))
#define GPIO_CONTROL (*((volatile unsigned int *)(GPIOCBASE+0x04)))
#define GPIO_BSRR    (*((volatile unsigned int *)(GPIOCBASE+0x10)))
void notmain ( void )
{
    volatile unsigned int ra;

    RCC_APB2ENR|=1<<4; //enable port c
    GPIO_CONTROL=(GPIO_CONTROL&(~0xF<<20))|(0x1<<20);
    while(1)
    {
        GPIO_BSRR=1<<(13+0);
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) continue;
        GPIO_BSRR=1<<(13+16);
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) continue;
    }
}
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}

arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m3 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -march=armv7-m -c blinker01.c -o blinker01.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o blinker01.elf -T flash.ld flash.o blinker01.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D blinker01.elf > blinker01.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy blinker01.elf blinker01.bin -O binary
```

then examine the listing

```
08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000025    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r5}
 8000008:   0800002b    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r3, r5}
 800000c:   0800002b    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r3, r5}
 8000010:   0800002b    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r3, r5}
 8000014:   0800002b    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r3, r5}
 8000018:   0800002b    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r3, r5}
 800001c:   0800002b    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r3, r5}
 8000020:   0800002b    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r3, r5}

08000024 <reset>:
 8000024:   f000 f802   bl  800002c <notmain>
 8000028:   e7ff        b.n 800002a <hang>

0800002a <hang>:
 800002a:   e7fe        b.n 800002a <hang>
```

the vector table has to be in the right place which it is. the vectors have to be the address orred with 1 which they are (.thumb_func in gnu assembler makes the next label a function and does the or one thing for us if we use that label for anything).  If your binary does not start with the vector table or the addresses are even then it is game over you wont boot.

Intel hex version of the binary if your tools can handle that

```
:020000040800F2
:1000000000100020250000082B0000082B0000082D
:100010002B0000082B0000082B0000082B00000814
:100020002B00000800F002F8FFE7FEE74FF4005550
:1000300000204FF00054154A154E1368154943F03F
:10004000100313603268144B02F07F4242F48012B6
:1000500082B032600D600190019A9A420FD90C6013
:100060000190019A9A42F5D8019A01320192019ABF
:100070009A42F9D90D600190019A9A42EFD8019AFB
:1000800001320192019A9A42F9D9E8E71810024028
:0C00900004100140101001403F0D03005F
:0400000508000000EF
:00000001FF
```

srecord version of the same.

```
S0110000626C696E6B657230312E73726563CB
S3150800000000100020250000082B0000082B0000081F
S315080000102B0000082B0000082B0000082B00000806
S315080000202B00000800F002F8FFE7FEE74FF4005542
S3150800003000204FF00054154A154E1368154943F031
S31508000040100313603268144B02F07F4242F48012A8
S3150800005082B032600D600190019A9A420FD90C6005
S315080000600190019A9A42F5D8019A01320192019AB1
S315080000709A42F9D90D600190019A9A42EFD8019AED
S3150800008001320192019A9A42F9D9E8E7181002401A
S3110800009004100140101001403F0D030051
S70508000000F2
```

if you move your led over to pc13 you can ideally use one of these binaries directly as is.

If you have openocd up then telnet to it (telnet localhost 4444)

```
> halt
> flash write_image erase /path/to/blinker01.srec
> reset
```

and it will start blinking the led

Comment: It seems i will have to pause my bare metal plans and be well acquainted with stm32 first. Thanks alot for the help though. I dont just understand GNU well enough yet. Is it possible to do bare metal with keil? I appreciate the help

Comment: yep, no reason why you cant use keil.  historically that is keils primary market.

Comment: I have tried using keil and writing to the registers after including startup files in the setup procedure, but its not working. am wondering if bare  metal must be done with gnu toolchain

Comment: can pretty much guarantee that is not the case, would be a fairly broken compiler if it cannot honor the C language.

Comment: I think you are doing it right, the volatile thing is C not GNU, I recommend you try it, you can take my C code as is and modify for port D0 and/or just use PC13 but build with Keil instead of GNU.  I recommend you try to figure out how to examine the binary to see that they are doing the basics right (vector table is cortex-m style not traditional, this is all thumb code no arm, etc).

Comment: @ched, Do you use uvision+stlink? If so there is a linker option for setting your data range which is typically in IRAM and for Arm cortex M0 is typically in the range of 0X20000000 and also the code download address which is 0x80000000(top sector). 0x4000000 is for the peripheral registers what is the starting address for your code?